# QGIS 2.0.1 connecting to ESRI WMTS jpeg vs jpg

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, jpg, wmts, global-mapper

I'm currently trying to troubleshoot an issue I have connecting to ESRI WMTS services.

Esri ArcGIS Server seems to provide the format as JPEG via the rest service, but in the get capabilites document they specify JPG - which it seems QGIS and Global Mapper don't want to recognise. Would the norm amongst mapping clients be JPG, JPEG or Both?

I've included the URL to our server if anyone is keen to try it out, I've also attached an image of what I get in QGIS

http://www.topofthesouthmaps.co.nz/arcgis/rest/services/CacheAerial/MapServer/WMTS

[image: QGIS to ESRI WMTS]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I get the same issue here with our JPG services (10.1).  I even tried to force the issue - appending **&format="jpeg"** to the end of the WMTS url, but to no avail.

Comment: I can get it to work within the browser using this format. Do you think you could edit the format tag in the capabilities file, Change it to JPEG instead of JPG?

**Test with .jpg** - 

http://www.topofthesouthmaps.co.nz/arcgis/rest/services/CacheAerial/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/CacheAerial/default/default028mm/19/860387/333241.jpg

**Test with .jpeg** - 

http://www.topofthesouthmaps.co.nz/arcgis/rest/services/CacheAerial/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/CacheAerial/default/default028mm/19/860387/333241.jpeg